# Activate symfony internal reverse proxy and link to only a redis server

Tags: php, symfony, redis, reverse-proxy, http-caching

I'd like my symfony application to use the [symfony internal reverse proxy](https://symfony.com/doc/current/the-fast-track/en/21-cache.html#activating-the-symfony-http-cache-kernel).
This is really easy:

```yaml
# config/packages/framework.yaml
framework:
    http_cache:
        enabled: true
        debug: true
        trace_level: 'full'
```

```php
// src/Controller/MyController.php
final class MyController
{
    #[Route('/articles', name: 'articles')]
    #[Cache(public: true, mustRevalidate: true, expires: 'tomorrow')]
    public function test(Request $request, TagAwareCacheInterface $cache, Environment $twig): Response
    {
        $page = $request->query->get('page', 1);

        $item = $cache->get("articles-page-{$page}", function(ItemInterface $item) use ($page, $twig) {
            if ($item->isHit()) {
                return $item->get();
            }

            // expensive algorithm to calculate $content variable
            // ...

            $item->set($content);

            return $item->get();
        });

        return new Response($item);
    }
```

So far so good, I now have this controller cached correctly into my filesystem.

I wanted my new http cache system to store exclusively into a redis server.
So I added this:

```yaml
# config/packages/cache.yaml
framework:
    cache:
        app: cache.adapter.redis
        default_redis_provider: redis://redis:6379
```

This does not work as expected as it sets both my redis and the filesystem caches.

When I empty my redis, reloading my url proves that my application uses the filesystem as http cache too.

```php
// public/index.php
require_once dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload_runtime.php';

return function (array $context) {
    $kernel = new Kernel($context['APP_ENV'], (bool) $context['APP_DEBUG']);
    $cacheKernel = new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\HttpCache\HttpCache($kernel);

    return $cacheKernel;
};
```

How do I do to only have the redis store for the http cache ?

Env:

`"symfony/framework-bundle": "^6.1"`

`"predis/predis": "^2.0"`

Comment: When you say “reloading my url proves that my application uses the filesystem as http cache too” how does it get proven? Also, are you saying the same thing gets cached on file system as in Redis?

Comment: Although I empty my redis, the request is still too fast until I clean var/cache/* as well.
So to sum up, my request is very fast if I have either cache store filled. If both are empty, then my request takes some amount of time